# Consumer hardware to click keys/initiate macros with mind control?

Tags: brain-computer-interface

Does anything exist (relatively cheap, off the shelf) that allows people to initiate simple actions using their brain waves (not with the mouth, eyes, expressions, etc)?

Example, I put a "helmet" on and can click the F5 key with my mind.

Don't need to be able to differentiate between too many keys, ~5 would be enough I'd say.

Comment: Lol.  That's totally 'The Rage: Carrie 2'